# SELECT attribute with MIN value from set of attribute instances that are part of specific row?

Tags: postgresql, select, join

I know my question is probably very vague and hard to understand at first glance, and i've sat 30 minutes thinking about a proper title. However my database knowledge is very limited so I have a hard time formulating myself properly yet.

It is part of a school assignment I'm currently doing, where the following is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

and an ER diagram I made of the system:
[image]

What I'm trying to accomplish is, selecting the quantity of the component within the computer_system that has the lowest quantity (current stock) so that I in the dataset I am printing out, am able to state exactly how many of each computer_system the store is able to sell, based on the lowest current quantity of any component the computer_system consists of.

This is the query that i am currently working with to accomplish it, but I've had multiple problems with quantity being ambiguous and other errors every time I try to make a fix. I have consulted a dozen of friends from class, but without luck.

```
SELECT 
computer_system.NAME,
cpu.name as cpu,
gpu.name as gpu, 
board.name as mainboard,
pccase.name as pc_case, 
ram.name as ram,
component.quantity as qty,
(cpu.price *1.3+ board.price*1.3 + pccase.price*1.3 + ram.price*1.3 + gpu.price*1.3) as computer_system_price

FROM computer_system, component
join component cpu on cpu.id = computer_system.cpu 
join component gpu on gpu.id = computer_system.gpu 
join component board on board.id = computer_system.mainboard 
join component pccase on pccase.id = computer_system.pc_case 
join component ram on ram.id = computer_system.ram
JOIN component qty ON qty.quantity = (SELECT MIN(component.quantity) FROM component WHERE component.id IN
                (computer_system.pc_case, 
                computer_system.mainboard,
                computer_system.cpu, 
                computer_system.gpu, 
         computer_system.ram))
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code fixed it for me:

```
SELECT computer_system.name AS "System name",
       cpu.name             AS "CPU",
       gpu.name             AS "GPU",
       pc_case.name         AS "Case",
       mainboard.name       AS "Mainboard",
       ram.name             AS "RAM",
       FLOOR((cpu.price + mainboard.price + pc_case.price + ram.price + coalesce(gpu.price, 0))*1.3/100)*100+99 AS "System price",
       SYSTEM.maxamount

FROM   computer_system
       join (SELECT name,
                    id,
                    price
             FROM   component) AS cpu
         ON cpu.id = computer_system.cpu
    left join (SELECT name,
                    id,
                    price
             FROM   component) AS gpu
         ON coalesce(gpu.id,0) = computer_system.gpu
       join (SELECT name,
                    id,
                    price
             FROM   component) AS pc_case
         ON pc_case.id = computer_system.pc_case
       join (SELECT name,
                    id,
                    price
             FROM   component) AS mainboard
         ON mainboard.id = computer_system.mainboard
       join (SELECT name,
                    id,
                    price
             FROM   component) AS ram
         ON ram.id = computer_system.ram
       join (SELECT computer_system.name,
                    Min(component.quantity) AS maxamount
             FROM   computer_system,
                    component
             WHERE  computer_system.cpu = component.id
                     OR computer_system.gpu = component.id
                     OR computer_system.mainboard = component.id
                     OR computer_system.pc_case = component.id
                     OR computer_system.ram = component.id
             GROUP  BY computer_system.name) AS SYSTEM
         ON SYSTEM.name = computer_system.name;
```